# libgdx liquidfun integration runtime error

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, box2d, noclassdeffounderror, liquidfun

I'm new to this. I generated a new project using libgdx project generator, all worked fine. Then I tried to add liquidfun extension to the library using the following tutorial: https://github.com/finnstr/gdx-liquidfun-extension/wiki/Setup.
It compiles all the dependencies are seen in the editor but at runtime I get this error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World; 10-09 10:29:50.698
>   12790-12895/com.mygdx.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.createBox2DWorld(MyGdxGame.java:87)
>
> Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mygdx.game.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mygdx.game.android-1/lib/arm,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

I am concered of this part of the tutorial which is made for eclipse. I don't know how to configure this in Android Studio.

> To do so you should right click on android project and select
>   Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add external Jar and pick
>   core/libs/gdx-liquidfun.jar. Last step is to check this library in
>   Order and export.

Note: I also tried to load the native libraries and they throw no error.

```
 static {
        System.loadLibrary("gdx-liquidfun");
        System.loadLibrary("gdx-box2d");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I had to right click the jar and Add As Library. I had to copy the jar to android/libs. The one from core/libs didn't have the option to Add as Library

Comment: Saved my bacon.  Thanks.

Comment: I know this post was a long time ago but I have a problem, I copied  gdx-liquidfun.jar to Android -> libs then right click and add as library. But I still get the error.